# Atom haskell IDE autocompletion and typeinfo not working

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

I installed atom-haskell packages for syntax coloring, autocompletion and typeinfo but only syntax coloring is working. I installed every dependency (ghc-mod, ghc-modi and hlint). I added paths to dependencies in package haskell-ghc-mod. Everything should be working ... (Project is created via cabal).

EDIT: I dive deeper into into it and I realized that autocompletion depends on ghc-mod browse module command. And when I use this command, it returns nothing. It seems like a bug in ghc-mod for me. Any ideas what to do?

EDIT: this is strange. ghc-mod has working typeinfo, but in Atom, no typeinfo ...

EDIT: cabal version is 1.16.0.2

EDIT: ghc-mod version is 5.3.0.0

EDIT: Interesting. Only thing which is working is coloring ... the rest not works ... It's stupid, after more than 20 years of Haskell development, theres no "usable" IDE for it. I tryed emacs ... again, only coloring ...

Comment: "I added paths to dependencies in package haskell-ghc-mod" - that's the `ghc-mod`, `ghc-modi`, ... right? (usually you'll want your path to include `~/.cabal/bin` if you installed it with `cabal install ghc-mod ...`)

Comment: ghc-mod is connected with Atom, theres no error in path to it

Comment: What version of cabal, ghc-mod are you using? Not all versions of cabal work with all versions of ghc-mod.

Comment: I never used Atom so sorry if I am stupid but is there no log or something where you can see the interaction with ghc-mod? (... ghc-mod was a bit on the rough side for the last few months although it really should be fixed now - maybe you can try to compile it in a sandbox straight from github - that fixes all the issues I had with it in emacs ;) )

Comment: Theres no log with ghc-mod usage. Or it is but I can't find it ...

Comment: Not an answer to your immediate question, but have you tried leksah recently? Its improved a lot.

Comment: I tried it some months ago, and I was disgusted. It created it's own database of packages and finally, it didn't run any program. so no, Leksah never more.

Comment: If you file an issue on https://github.com/atom-haskell/ide-haskell/issues, I will do my best to help you sort this out. I don't think SO is the best place to provide support of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are still using the ghc-mod version you said you are(version is 5.3.0.0), but in the docs (https://atom.io/packages/haskell-ghc-mod) it explicitly says the following:

> Supported ghc-mod versions are from 4.1.0 to 5.2.1.2.

Try to rm and enforce this version.

According to stackage (https://www.stackage.org/package/ghc-mod) your version was published 14-Aug-2015 and the one supported by the atom plugin was published 8 months ago, 2014-12-31 v5.2.1.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working with supported ghc-mod version